# Why isn't compiler time error thrown when we call to a C function

Tags: c++, c

According to the example which the Standard provides at `N4296::13.3.3 [over.match.best]`

```
namespace A 
{
    extern "C" void f(int = 5);
}

namespace B 
{
    extern "C" void f(int = 5);
}

using A::f;
using B::f;

void use() 
{
    f(3); // OK, default argument was not used for viability
    f(); // Error: found default argument twice
}
```

As the Standard says at `N4296::7.5/6 [dcl.link]`:

> Two declarations for a function with C language linkage with the same
>   function name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that
>   appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same function.

I tried to explore such a thing on my own example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    extern "C" void foo(int a = 5){ std::cout << a << "1" << std::endl; }
}

namespace B
{
    extern "C" void foo(int a = 5);
}

using A::foo;
using B::foo;

int main()
{ 
    foo(); //Error 
    foo(2);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d952d5fe5a3a691)**

So why does my example work? What's differences between my example and the Standard's example unless I defined the function explicitly in the `A` namespace? Why is that so important?

Comment: I'm just curious as to what is the meaning of an `extern "C"` function within a C++ namespace.

Comment: Re: "What's differences between my example and the Standard's example unless I defined the function explicitly in the A namespace?": I just tried editing your demo to *not* define the function explicitly, and it still compiled fine. (Linking failed, of course.) So that's not the difference. It seems that g++ simply doesn't give an error in this situation.

Comment: [Clang accepts it too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c544e25d8dcdac8). Hmm... Btw, an important part of the spec missing from your question: *"If the best viable function resolves to a function for which multiple declarations were found, and if at least two of these declarations — or the declarations they refer to in the case of using-declarations — specify a default argument that made the function viable, the program is ill-formed."* Sounds like a Clang and g++ defect?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It lets you access functions from a library without colliding with the same identifier used elsewhere in the C++ code.

Comment: This looks like a case where the standard is at fault, so the implementations have ignored it. It's hard to see how letting this through would be the wrong thing to do (apart from being non-compliant, obviously).

Comment: @TonyK Most compilers do flat-out reject `void f(int = 3); void f(int = 3);`, though. Allowing it here is at least inconsistent.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, you are right -- I didn't know that, but experiments comfirm it for gcc 4.9.0 and clang 3.4.1.

Comment: @hvd: Sorry, I edited my comment while you were posting yours.

Comment: Compile time errors are not 'thrown'. They are *printed.* It is *exceptions* that are thrown, at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already in the comments, there is no relevant difference between the standard's example, and your example. Compilers that properly implement the standard issue a diagnostic for both.

The fact that this is clearly a compiler bug in at least clang and Intel can be seen when you edit the example to the nonsensical

```
namespace A
{
    extern "C" void f(int = 5);
}

namespace B
{
    extern "C" void f(int = 3); // different default argument
}

using A::f;
using B::f;

void use()
{
    f(); // No error !
}
```

Despite getting two *different* default arguments, no error or even a warning is generated. One of the default arguments is used, the first with Intel, the second with clang.

GCC does happen to reject this nonsensical example, so there is no quick and easy way to verify that it is clearly a bug in GCC as well, but that doesn't change the fact that it is: as noted, it silently accepts the example from the standard where the standard points out where an error should be detected.